# How to update multiple a rows in mysql

Tags: sql, mysqli

I have a database table like :

```
        +---+-------------+
        |id |ship_method  | 
        +---+-------------+
        | 1 |freeshipping |     
        | 1 | flatrate    |
        | 2 |    DHL      |
        | 3 | matrixrate  |
        | 1 |    courier  |
        +---+-------------+
```

So, I want to update ship_method from frontend form based on multi option selected.
For eg : if Id 1 selects freeshipping , DHL , matrixrate then the corresponding values of ship_method should be updated.

What is the mysql query to update in this case. I tried but couldn't find how to update such multiple rows at once.

Comment: delete previous data and insert new all  delete from table where id=1;  insert into table_name values(1,'freeshipping').......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete previous data and insert new all

```
delete from table where id=1;  
insert into table_name(id,ship_method) values(1,'freeshipping'),(1,'DHL'),(1,'matrixrate');
```